# Rails / Devise Session Destroyed When Redirected From Paypal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, paypal

Using Paypal payment standard. When the user is redirect the back to the app after paying on paypal.com, the logged in user becomes signed out. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you post to a rails app without providing the correct **CSRF parameters**, your **session gets deleted**. This sounds like what is happening. One way to solve this is to disable the CSRF meta protection for the paypal post action

In Rails3 you can disable the csrf token in your controller for particular methods:

---

**In your controller:**
 1. `protect_from_forgery :except => :create`

or

 2. `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token`

or

 to disable it for everything except a few methods:
 
3. `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :except => [:update, :create]`

Comment: That was the issue thanks for the help Francois. I just need to add that PayPal will post data to both notify_url (IPN) and the return_url. There more you got to make sure both methods do not have CSRF parameters on.

Comment: if you want to remove CSRF on more than one method you can use :only instead of :except and then specify your methods as you need them, eg. :only => [:method1, :method2]